# How many leaves has a complete binary tree with N internal nodes?

Tags: tree, binary-tree, nodes

Given the number of internal nodes (N), how many leaves does a complete binary tree have? For the same number of internal nodes (N), how many leaves does a full binary tree have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For a complete binary tree with n nodes, how many nodes are leaf nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823382/for-a-complete-binary-tree-with-n-nodes-how-many-nodes-are-leaf-nodes)

Comment: that one has n nodes, in my problem there are n internal nodes